# INDEX-MATCH for partial match of reference row with multiple lookup values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the below two (shortened) tables:

A1:A5 - Data table

```
URL
shop.samsung.com/au/accessories/mobile-accessories
samsung.com/us/amp/us/smartphones/galaxy-s9
samsung.com/us/appliances/electric-ranges
samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/notice.html
```

E1:F5 - Reference Table

```
If Folder Contains          Value
mobile-accessories          Mobile Accessories
smartphones                 Mobile Phone
appliances/electric-ranges  Cooking Appliance
appliances/refrigerators    Semiconductor
```

I'm trying to create a formula that will look at the URL table, check if the string has a partial match in the Reference table's "If Folder Contains" column, and return the Value.  For example, if I choose the first link (A2) I would expect the formula to return "Mobile Accessories" since A2 contains "mobile-accessories" in the URL.

The reverse I know how to do (simply do a vlookup with a wildcard before/after), but I can't figure out a way to do this.  Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Do it by a macro (VBA function).

Comment: Is there a native way to do this without resorting to VBA?

Comment: Maybe it exists... I do not see it now, in a linear form at least. And if exists, it will be expencive because of array formulas, I think...

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering if *appliances/refrigerators* should map to *Semiconductor* as you have shown in your example. I though may be *business/semiconductor* might map to *Semiconductor*. But that's not an issue.

In this example sample URL data is in A1:A5, mapping table is in E1:F5.
Now in B2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

Drag it down up to the intended rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($E$2:$E$5,A2)),0,ROW($E$2:$E$5))-ROW($F$1))),"No Category")
```

[image]

The Outer IFERROR is added only for cosmetic purposes, just to show 'No Category' text if no match is found. If in case your version of EXCEL is before 2007, you can drop it. Instead of "No category" message, formula shall just return error for such instances or alternatively you can also use mix of IF(ISERROR()) construct.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve the issue yon need helper Column to store Partial Match Strings.**

[image]

*Write this formula in Cell `N41` & fill down.*

```
=VLOOKUP($N36,$O36:$O36,1,TRUE)
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*